# How to log insert, update, delete sqls with ebean ORM in play 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1, ebean

Does anyone know to  log insert, update, delete sqls with ebean ORM in play 2.1. I don't want to log any select sqls.

I know turn on it in application.conf

```
db.default.logStatements=true
logger.com.jolbox=DEBUG
```

But that will include all the select sqls. I know the current ebean verison 2.7.7 has an API.

```
setLoggingLevelIud
```

It looks like do what I expect. But it seems the ebean lib used in play 2.1 doesn't include this API. I checked the version of ebean in play 2.1. It shows version 3.x. I feel confused... Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know how to update the Play2 Ebean version, you can check ebean current version on their github project: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm